# Can't load expdp data dump

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I've been given a data dump by a client created with this command:

```
    expdp system/"redacted pw" full=Y directory=WORK dumpfile=IM_DB_EXP_20171010.dmp logfile=IM_DB_EXP_20171010.log
```

Now am I correct in thinking that this will just export the system schema?

I don't think the client has created their tables in the system schema (a bad idea I think), so what they've given me isn't their actual app data?

Comment: `full=Y`, you're getting the entire database.

Comment: A good reference: http://dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_expdp_tips.htm

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a full export which is denoted by the `full=Y`. If you're looking for only schema try something like:

```
expdp system/"redacted pw" schemas=MYSCHEMA directory=WORK IM_DB_EXP_20171010.dmp logfile=IM_DB_EXP_20171010.log

impdp system/"redacted pw" schemas=MYSCHEMA directory=WORK IM_DB_EXP_20171010.dmp logfile=IM_DB_EXP_20171010.log
```

You have many additional options for controlling EXP/IMPDP as well. Check this out: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g as well as the links in the comments.

Comment: If you know what schema you need, you can work with the dump you have. Just tell the import what schema you are interested in as pointed out here.
No need for a new dump when this is a onetime occasion.

Comment: So this dump should contain ALL schemas within the database? If there is data within a schema X, this will be included in the dump?

I need to know what schema the clients tables are created in I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your help all. I can (at least) now access the dump file and generate DDL from it that tells me all the users and schemas.

Sadly, I can upload it because it it exceeds the 11gig limit on Oracle Express :-(

Still, one step forward.